# Como cambiar un valor de un campo(Haskell)

Tags: estructuras-de-datos, haskell

Estoy trabado con este ejercicio que me piden:

`cambioDeNombre :: String -> Persona -> Persona`

> Dados un nombre y una persona, devuelve una persona con la edad de la persona y el
> nuevo nombre.

Y tengo la siguiente estructura del registro :

```hs
data Persona = P String Int String  -- Nombre Edad DNI
```

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo cambio un valor de un campo de ese registro?

Saludos!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que dices ser un *registro* en haskell es un *tipo de dato*, los [registros](https://www.haskellforall.com/2020/07/record-constructors.html) son otra cosa. Por otro lado, hay que tener claro que en haskell todas las variables son inmutables. Cambiar un valor es crear un nuevo objeto con el nuevo valor.

Tu función `cambioDeNombre`, debe crear un dato de tipo `Persona` a partir de otro `Persona`, usando la descomposición de tipos para obtener las partes `edad` y `dni`:

```hs
data Persona = P String Int String -- Nombre Edad DNI

cambioDeNombre :: String -> Persona -> Persona
cambioDeNombre nombre persona = P nombre edad dni
   where P _ edad dni = persona
```

Se puede hacer incluso más directo, aunque menos inteligible:

```hs
data Persona = P String Int String -- Nombre Edad DNI

cambioDeNombre :: String -> Persona -> Persona
cambioDeNombre nombre (P _ edad dni) = P nombre edad dni
```